# Peer to peer notifications using phonegap

Tags: php, cordova, push-notification

I am using phonegap to develop an app that includes users sending other users private messages and other general notifications. 
Is there a tutorial or plugin on how to do this effectively? 
Thanks

Comment: You can't send peer to peer push notifications. You need to use GCM and APNS

Comment: @Emre Yes, so GCM and APNS would act as middle men, I am still wondering if there is a plugin or tutorial for phonegap on this